# Mysql Loop through selected column and execute Insert query in the loop

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to loop over selected slugs and execute little complicated INSERT INTO SELECT query.
`slugs[iteration]` usage is not a correct mysql syntax. But I have to access fetched slugs one by one inside the query. How Could I achieve that ?

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE create_sitemap_from_slugs()
BEGIN
    SELECT `slug`  INTO slugs FROM slug_table;
    SELECT COUNT(*)  INTO count FROM slug_table;

    SET iteration = 0;

    START TRANSACTION;

        WHILE iteration < count DO

            INSERT INTO line_combinations
                SELECT REPLACE(`line`, '{a}', slugs[iteration]) AS `line`
                FROM line_combinations
                WHERE `line` LIKE CONCAT('%/', '{a}', '%');

            SET iteration = iteration + 1;

        END WHILE;

    COMMIT;


END
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Btw, I don't want to use any external programming language to make this, this procedure will be working for billions of rows. I read Loops in SQL is not a good way due to performance concerns.

If you suggest another way I would accept this also.

I  asked another detailed question but couldn't get an answer. if you would like to check that also : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35320494/fetch-placeholders-from-table-and-place-into-generated-line-combination-pattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So for each line with `{a}` you need to insert `COUNT(*) from slug_table` times values filled with `slug` value.

It seems you can do that just in one INSERT from SELECT

```
INSERT INTO line_combinations
            (SELECT REPLACE(lc.line, '{a}', st.slug) AS `line`
            FROM line_combinations lc, slug_table st
            WHERE lc.line LIKE CONCAT('%/', '{a}', '%');
```

UPDATE:

You can create a temp table `line_combinations2` and insert all the records

```
FROM line_combinations 
WHERE line LIKE CONCAT('%/', '{a}', '%')
```

into the temp table. Then just use the temp table in the INSERT instead of original one

Comment: now it says `Can't reopen table: line_combinations`  I think it locks the table while inserting, streaming doesn't work.

Comment: you can create a temp table **line_combinations2** and insert all the records FROM line_combinations WHERE line LIKE CONCAT('%/', '{a}', '%') into the temp table. Then just use the temp table in the INSERT instead of original one

Comment: you are correct there are 5 placeholders like {a} http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35320494/fetch-placeholders-from-table-and-place-into-generated-line-combination-pattern I think there would be 5 or 6 temporary tables, anyway I think there isn't make this query more simpler :) Could you please update your answer due to this change I accept your answer.